# Counter function use in an insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, sql-function

I need to make an insert to a table by using a function. What I do is:

```
UPDATE  MyTable SET MyColumn = dbo.fncGetMyValue(MyParameter) where //some logic
```

Here MyParameter is of course a column in MyTable. The thing is, as long as I update one row, the value of the function should change, because it's actually a counter function for MyParemeter. But the query inserts the same and first result of the function for each row it updates. I mean, it should make the updates like 15, 16, 17... for each row, but it updates like 15, 15, 15,... I guess it's normal as sql do not see the values inserted until the insert process ends.

My question is if there is a way to fix this without using a while statement?

Comment: What does `dbo.fncGetMyValue()` do? I suspect this will be the key to finding a set based alternative to your problem.

Comment: Thanks paqogomez, I've added MS SQL Server to the title. Gareth, what dbo.fncGetMyValue(parameter) does is, it returns greatest record + 1 of MyColumn where another column = MyParameter.

Comment: Please add your logic that determines the ordering of records for update.  Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Where logic is completely out of topic. It's about ID's of the records to be updated and says ID IN (SELECT .....). SQL Server Version is 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have been fairly frugal with specifics, so I have had to guess at some of your logic, but if I follow your logic that your function gets the greatest record + 1, you should still be able to do this in a set based manner:

First I will explain with a SELECT, which should then be adaptable to an UPDATE, essentially the problem you are having is that MaxRecord + 1 is the same for all rows, as it would be with the following SELECT:

```
SELECT  t.ID,
        t.MyColumn,
        t.MyParamter,
        MaxRecord = MaxT.MyColumn + 1
FROM    MyTable AS t
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  MyParameter, MyColumn = MAX(MyColumn)
            FROM    MyTable
            WHERE   SomeLogic
            GROUP BY MyParamter
        ) AS MaxT
            ON MaxT.MyParamter = t.MyParamter
WHERE   SomeLogic;
```

You can avoid this by removing the +1 and adding `ROW_NUMBER()` instead:

```
MaxRecord = MaxT.MyColumn + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.MyParameter ORDER BY t.ID)
```

Finally, you can also remove the subquery by using an analytic function too, so your final select will be:

```
SELECT  t.ID,
        t.MyParameter,
        t.MyColumn,
        MyNewColumn = MAX(t,MyColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY t.MyParameter) +
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.MyParameter
                                            ORDER BY t.ID)
FROM    MyTable t
WHERE   SomeLogic;
```

Then to do the update you can just wrap all this in a CTE and update that:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  t.ID,
            t.MyParameter,
            t.MyColumn,
            MyNewColumn = MAX(t,MyColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY t.MyParameter) +
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.MyParameter
                                                ORDER BY t.ID)
    FROM    MyTable t
    WHERE   SomeLogic
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     MyColumn = MyNewColumn;
```